# Excel form ActiveX control moving itself

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet where one tab is a rigidly formatted form containing a bunch of ActiveX comboboxes and option buttons. Multiple people use this form on different computers and versions of Excel. I have the whole thing, spreadsheet and workbook, protected, but nonetheless occasionally on opening the form all of the controls move upward. The issue seems to be caused by different screen resolutions.

To deal with this I've long ago created a script that lines everything up with the row and column where it should be.

```
Sub ResizeCombo(ByRef cbo As Shape, ByVal rw As Long, ByVal cl As Long, ByVal wid As Long)

    cbo.Height = Intake.Cells(rw, cl).Height - 1
    cbo.Top = Intake.Cells(rw, cl).Top + 1
    cbo.Left = Intake.Cells(rw, cl).Left + 1
    cbo.Width = wid    
End Sub

Sub ResizeCheckbox(ByRef cbo As Shape, ByVal rw As Long, ByVal cl As Long)
    cbo.Height = Intake.Cells(rw, cl).Height - 1
    cbo.Top = Intake.Cells(rw, cl).Top + 1
    cbo.Left = Intake.Cells(rw, cl).Left + 6
    cbo.Width = Intake.Cells(rw, cl).MergeArea.Width - 7
End Sub

Sub ResizeCombos()
    ResizeCombo Intake.Shapes("School"), 11, 1, 144

    ResizeCombo Intake.Shapes("obGenderMale"), 20, 8, 45
    ResizeCombo Intake.Shapes("obGenderFemale"), 20, 9, 50
```

This has worked for the last year, but a few days ago stopped working. When I debug it I see the control move to the right spot and then "snap back" as though it is locked in place. Normally the script gets run with everything locked but I've tried it unlocked as well.

There are form controls, checkboxes, as well, and they move to the right spot and stay there.

Comment: Sorry this has happened, it was notorious in my old world as a long-standing, known bug... we stopped using in-sheet controls and started putting buttons as hyperlinks and activeX controls on separate popup userforms because buttons would resize, move, text would shrink or grow... it always happened when plugging in a laptop to a 2nd screen or after resolution changes, we tried to have routines to resize and reshape buttons etc. but it became more trouble than it was worth. I recommend rewiring your books if it's not too troublesome! We never looked back.

Comment: Long time ago, I have the same problem which never solved. Since I positioned my all activeX controls in the sheet based on the cell address, so I choose a cell where  the column width and the row height of the sheet is in default value, and create another macro just for positioning and resize the height and width based on that cell height and cell width. For example : `Set patok = Range("A1") .. With SearchBox ... .Height = patok.Height * 1 ... .Width = patok.Width * 2 ... .Top = Range("i2").Top .... .Left = Range("i2").Left .... End With`